# Changing background color of table row on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my first post here, so sorry if my post is a little confusing.

I'm working on an assignment which uses HTML5, CSS, and Javascript.  I'm trying to use javascript to change the color of a table row's background whenever a user hovers over that row. However, i've run into two issues.

Here's a link to the JSFiddle containing the entire code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bguqp/8/

The first issue seems to be with this segment of code.  This code alternates the rows colors.  When removed, the table row's background color changes as it should whenever I hover over a row.  However, if I include this code in the javascript file, the row background color does not change.

```
var tblrows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tblrows.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0) tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
    else tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#C0C0C0';
```

Second, while the code is working on JSFiddle, it does not seem to be working in my web browser when run, even with the code above removed from the javascript file.

*EDIT*

Here is the Javascript code responsible for changing the table row background color on hover

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table.stripe_table tr:odd").addClass("alternate");

    $("table.stripe_table tr").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("tr_onmouseover");
    });
    $("table.stripe_table tr").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("tr_onmouseover");
    });
    $("table.stripe_table tr").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("tr_onmouseclick");
    });
});
```

and the CSS code i'm using in conjunction with the above javascript code

```
table.stripe_table tr.alternate{
    background-color: #CCC;
}
table.stripe_table tr.tr_onmouseover{
    background-color: #FC0
}
table.stripe_table tr.tr_onmouseclick{
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Is changing the background color on hover with Javascript a requirement? Because this can all be done in CSS.

Comment: Yes it is a requirement.

Comment: Added the javascript/css code responsible for changing color on hover

Comment: Your problem is that hard-coded styles always take precedent over class styles.

Comment: Thanks.  Would that also explain why the code is not working in the browser as well?

Comment: That code actually is working--your classes are being added and removed just fine, I imagine. It's just that the classes that apply colors do nothing when there is a hard-coded color in place.

Comment: What did the browser console say on your computer?

Comment: That's what you need to know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function accommodations.html:94
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined atlantic.js:33

Comment: So that means a script is trying to access jQuery before jQuery is being loaded. Make sure that you are calling jQuery before any scripts that require it.

Comment: I have jQuery referenced in the header of the html file.

Comment: Added the [tag:jquery] tag, since it seems to be evidently in use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is CSS specificity. Adding a class to the TR will cancel out the CSS in the stylesheet. Instead of applying colors directly, add a class (even/odd).

Heck you do not even need a class, simple css rule can do zebra stripes.

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

And you say you need JavaScript for hover, in reality you needed it for old IE support. Modern day browsers can do it without JavaScript

```
table.stripe_table tr:hover{
    background-color: #FC0
}
```

only thing you would need to do is add a class for clicking on a row

```
table.stripe_table tr.selected{
    background-color: #F00
}
```

and the JavaScript

```
$(document).on("click","tbody tr", function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```